# Is it appropriate to go through questions editting them to add <kbd> tags?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

There is a user going through many posts and adding `<kbd>` tags to them. While the user does change some other things which should be changed about the post, there are many easily changeable things which this user ignores (such as a "Thanks!"). [This is an example of such an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12714052). [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12713880) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12713921) the user's recent edits have been approved [or are](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12713917) [near approval](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12713962), but I don't feel like these changes are enough to be an actual edit.

Comment: You have to ignore the fact that all the edits are from the same user. Just rate each edit in isolation: If they improve most of the issues of a post, approve and/or edit it; if there are several things still not fixed, reject and/or edit it.